# Delete user and user created data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a site where users can create posts and messages.
I want it so that when a user delete's their profile, that all user's posts and messages will be deleted as well. I have a users, messages, and posts table. I was thinking of just doing something like

```
User::destroy(Auth->user()->id); //to delete user
Message::where(user_id, Auth->user())->delete(); //to delete al messages from that user
Post::where(user_id, Auth->user())->delete(); //to delete all posts from that user
```

Is this the best way, or is there a more elegant option? Do i need to basically search all my tables for that user_id then delete each row?

Comment: Yes, it is called the DB [triggers](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=DB+triggers&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) or store procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, in your migration, you will want to set up foreign key constraints   with an onDelete method.

This would live in your posts table.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

This would live in your messages table.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Check out the foreign key constraints on this.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

The other option if you cant modify your migrations for some reason is to do triggers.

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) { 
         $user->posts()->delete();
         $user->messages()->delete();
    });
}
```

This of course requires that you have relationships set up in your models.

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events